# Error in creating a new variable through a sum

Tags: r

I want to do the following sum in order to create a new variable in my dataframe "e10" (the one that has 2000 rows, as especified in the code below this one):

```
e10$Antip <- (e10$AntPT + e10$AntPSDB + e10$AntPMDB)
```

But then, this error occurs:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Antip, value = numeric(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 2000
```

Does anyone know what could have happened? Thanks :)

Comment: are these columns numeric i.e. can you show the `str(e10)` or do you have any list column

Comment: Check the spelling and case of your column names. I get the same exact where when I do `mtcars$new1 <- (mtcars$cyl + mtcars$disp + mtcars$quux)` (whereas `mtcars$new1 <- (mtcars$cyl + mtcars$disp)` works just fine), because `mtcars$quux` returns `NULL`.

Comment: all the other variables are numeric and don't return NULL, no error.

Comment: guys, I realized where I was mistaken! thank you so much for your time, anyway. have a nice week :)

Comment: the mistake was mine, actually. I just realized that I nominated two variables with the same name, unintentionally. so it was something I had to realize myself. sorry.